# Error creating rdd in apache spark with mongodb configuration

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to create rdd with connection to mongodb,with the following command:

```
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
        inputFormatClass='com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoInputFormat',
        keyClass='org.apache.hadoop.io.Text',
        valueClass='org.apache.hadoop.io.MapWritable',
        conf={
             'mongo.input.uri': 'mongodb://ip:27017/db.collection'
        }
      )
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
```

I am using spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4 and mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.0.jar ,mongo-java-driver-3.0.1.jar, mongodb-driver-3.0.3.jar

Also my command to start the pyspark is :

```
./pyspark --jars spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/mongo-hadoop-core-1.4.0.jar --driver-class-path spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.4/lib/mongo-java-driver-3.0.1.jar --master spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I'm facing the same one. Thanks